# Microphone start function freezes unity app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, audio-recording, microphone

Starting microphone completely freezes the entire application for 5 seconds (always 5 seconds). Unity 5.6.0f3

code:

```
public void StartRecording()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw1.Start();
        if (!Microphone.IsRecording(null))
        {
            m_ForcedStopRecording = false;
            m_RecordingStartTime = Time.time;
            Debug.Log("ms before start microphone 2: " + sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            m_RecordedAudio = Microphone.Start(null, false, m_MaxRecordingLengthInSeconds, m_RecordingFrequency);
            Debug.Log("ms after start microphone: " + sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            StartCoroutine(WaitForRecordingTimeout());
        }
        Debug.Log("total StartRecording: " + sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

ms before start microphone 2 result says 0
ms after start microphone says 5011
Any suggestions?

Comment: What value does `m_MaxRecordingLengthInSeconds` have? Is `Microphone.Start` a blocking call (which I bet)? If so, then that call is simply blocking your main thread.

Comment: The temporary freeze is a bug. File for a bug report. It looks like they are not making that call on another Thread. This should be an async function with a callback function when Microphone starts.

Comment: @Programmer even if it was a bug because of not being in async, why would it take ALWAYS 5 seconds to start? but not always also because if I restart computer it takes 2ms ans then suddenly without any pattern it starts taking 5 seconds to start the microphone which sounds weird

Comment: That function is enumerating Mics on your computer then starting it. It should be done in another Thread. It's not your fault. This is a problem with the API. You have to file for a bug report then wait for a fix or you can build native Mic plugins for the most used platforms(Windows, iOS, Android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try connecting your microphone to different port, it may be a problem of your computer having troubles finding your microphone if it's USB